# how to load an another html file on a button click in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am creating an application in phonegap using the jQuery mobile framework.

In my `index.html` file I have a two text boxes to accept username and password.

When I click on the submit button it calls a function `submitBtn()` that checks whether the username and password is correct or not and if it is correct then it should load a new html file that I have created `selectOption.html'

here is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var userName;
        var userPassword;

        $("#submitBtn").click(function() {
            //alert("HI");       
            userName = $("#UserName").val();
            userPassword = $("#Password").val();

            if ((!UserName)|| (!userPassword)) {
                alert("Enter the Details");
            }
            else {
                if ((userName !="alpha") ||(userPassword !="beta")) {
                    alert('Enter correct username and password');
                }
                else {
                    //here i want to load my selectOption.html file ?
                }              
            }                                   
        });                           
    });
</script>
```

my code under `<body>` is

```
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="home">         
        <div data-role="header">             
            <h1>Enter Credential</h1>                       
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">
            <label for="UserName">User Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="UserName" id="UserName" value="" style="width:220px;"  />

            <label for="Password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="Password" id="Password" value="" style="width:220px;"  />

            <div id="submitBtn" data-role="button">Submit</div>
        </div>  
    </div>
</body>
```

The function is getting called but how can I load the `selectOption.html` file?

Comment: When you say "load another file", do you mean "redirect to another file"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried using the jQuery Mobile method to perform navigation?

```
$.mobile.changePage("newpage.html");
```

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/api/methods.html

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer

to load any page you can simply do

`$.mobile.changePage("yourHTML.html","slideup");`